# Short interest and short volume does not add up

Tags: shorting-securities

I *know* the difference between short volume and short interest. The later the number of the outstanding shares that are now (or any other date) in a short position; while the former shows how many shares were shorted in a given day/week etc.

Now, theoretically, it is possible to have in 06/24/22 a short volume of 30K shares, but the short interest reported at the end of the day is only about 20K. Since though 30K new short were added, they could still have been covered even in the same trading day - say if the total volume that day was 100K shares.

However, in the example above, if the total volume on 06/24/22 was only 35K shares - that means we must have at least 25K shares reported as shorts at the end of the day. because only 5K of the 30K new shorts could be covered. if the reported data will show that we have 10K shares short at the end of the day, something does not make sense. (or I don't understand something).

I say this event just mentioned that does not make sense is indeed happening per FINRA official data. Now, because this happens in some OTC stock I'm reluctant to give any specific symbol, but from what I was able to skim - it is not rare at all: The reported short interest for some OTC stocks are very low (might be less than 10% from the avg. daily volume on some readings), while the short volume can be above 50%  for several days straight. So I either miss something or not reading FINRA data appropriately. your help is appreciated.

---

The official data for the short volume was taken from FINRA site ([here](https://www.finra.org/finra-data/browse-catalog/short-sale-volume-data/daily-short-sale-volume-files)). for OTC stocks I'm talking about the files are under: ORF. Here is an example [file](https://cdn.finra.org/equity/regsho/daily/FORFshvol20220414.txt) from 04/14 (a day which we also had short interest repots). The short interest report can be found [here](https://otce.finra.org/otce/equityShortInterest) - we have data only about twice a month.

(*) it might be that the short volume should not be taken at the day of the reporting but rather few days earlier because of settlements issues, but I insist an example can be easily found.